# SSIS fails if the data exists in the database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SQL database with Index Unique ID.
I am using SSIS to import data from Excel into a SQL database. If the ID exists in the database, I am getting an error Cannot insert a duplicate key row in the object with a unique index when there is a duplicate in my SQL Server database,  want I want to is the SSIS to skip importing this row, and jump to the next if the row(it's ID) exists in the database. How can I solve this?

Comment: *"How can I solve this problem?"* Don't insert the duplicate values.

Comment: You can either modify the Error Output of your destination to "redirect" or "ignore" instead of "fail component" or you can add a lookup to your data flow, which you modify to "redirect to output" and where you use the "not matched" output on your destination.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

1. **Aggregate Transformation with Conditional Split Transformation**

Bring Aggregate Transformation to Data Flow Pane and connect your Excel File Source to Aggregate Transformation. You need to group them and get count.

Drag Conditional Split Transformation to Data Flow Pane and connect Aggregate Transformation to it.

By using Conditional Split you will be redirecting duplicate records to output where you can write them to table/file.

Convert [Count All] to `Int` by using `Cast Function (DT_I4)`.

Conditional Split Transformation is going to create two outputs :

- `DuplicateRecords` for duplicate records
- `CorrectRecords` for unique records

Bring a `Multicast Transformation` and connect the `DuplicateRecords` output from `Conditional Split Transformation` to it.

Bring an OLE DB Destination and connect the `CorrectRecords` output output from `Conditional Split Transformation` to it.

Put Data Viewer between them so you can display the records. In real time you will be writing these records to your destination tables/files.

**2. Lookup Component :**

Add a `Lookup task` in the control flow and join the Excel File task with it.

In `Lookup Transformation Editor`,  specify the connection manager and cache type.

[image]

In the drop-down of Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries, select the following option :

```
Redirect rows to no match output
```

Click on Connections and specify the destination table from the drop-down. you have both the source and destination tables in the same database. You can create a separate connection here as well.

Click on the Columns, and it shows the source and destination table.
You want to compare the ID columns on both Excel file and your destination table . Drag on the ID column from the source and move it to the destination ID column.

Add an `OLE DB destination` from the SSIS Toolbox. Join the Lookup task with the `OLE DB destination`, and it opens the following Input-Output selection.

Select the following values :

- Output: Lookup No Match Output : you attach it to the `OLE DB destination` (table in SQL Server database )
- Input: OLE DB Destination Input : you attach it to a Flat file destination for example

**3. SSIS sort in combination with a Script Component :**

Add your source to the Data Flow Task.
You need to sort on the columns you want to use for deduplication. In general, If your source is a database table, then you should add a `GROUP BY` clause to the query else you should add a `SORT Transformation` right after your source.
Add a Script Component type Transformation after your sorted source.

Edit the `Script Component` and go to the `Input Columns tab` and select all the columns you want to use for deduplication as `ReadOnly` (the same fields as you used for sorting).

Go to the Inputs and Outputs tab and change the name of the Output port from "Output 0" to "Unique". Also change the ExclusionGroup to 1.

Add a new Output and give it the name Duplicate and change the `ExlusionGroup` to 1. To connect this new output port to the input port, change the `SynchronousInputID` property and select the input port.

Edit the Script and copy the following code. This script uses reflection to get all selected columns so that you don't have to change the script if you change the input columns. But read the coding comments.

```
// C# code
// This script automaticly compares the selected columns, but there is one 'bug':
// You have to edit and close this script again if you change input columns.
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;                                // Added
using System.Text;                                      // Added
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
 
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    // Create a variable to store the concatenated values for the previous row
    string previousRow = "";
 
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        // Create a variable to store the concatenated values of current row
        StringBuilder currentRow = new StringBuilder();
 
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // We can't use the _IsNull columns, so ignore them. Also ignore the new output column
            if ((p.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("_IsNull") == false) && (p.Name.Equals("Duplicate") == false))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Concatenate value as string to variable
                    currentRow.Append(p.GetValue(Row, null).ToString() + "|");
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    // If the value is NULL (empty) then you can't get the value of it
                    currentRow.Append("NULL|");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Raise error because something unexpected went wrong
                    bool pbCancel = false;
                    this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "MarkDuplicates", p.Name + ": " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0, out pbCancel);
                }
            }
        }
 
        // Check if the current row and previous row are the same
        if (currentRow.ToString().Equals(previousRow))
        {
            // Redirect to duplicate output
            Row.DirectRowToDuplicate();
        }
        else
        {
            // Redirect to unique output
            Row.DirectRowToUnique();
        }
 
        // Fill previous row with current value for next check
        previousRow = currentRow.ToString();
    }
}
```

or VB.Net :

```
' VB.Net code
' This script automaticly compares the selected columns, but there is one 'bug':
' You have to edit and close this script again if you change input columns.
 
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Reflection                           ' Added
Imports System.Text                                 ' Added
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
 
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
 
    ' Create a variable to store the concatenated values for the previous row
    Dim previousRow As String = ""
 
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        ' Create a variable to store the concatenated values of current row
        Dim currentRow As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
 
        Dim p As PropertyInfo
        For Each p In Row.GetType().GetProperties()
            ' We can't use the _IsNull columns, so ignore them. Also ignore the new output column
            If ((p.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("_IsNull") = False) And (p.Name.Equals("Duplicate") = False)) Then
                Try
                    ' Concatenate value as string to variable
                    currentRow.Append(p.GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString() + "|")
                Catch ex As ArgumentException
                    ' If the value is NULL (empty) then you can't get the value of it
                    currentRow.Append("NULL|")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Raise error because something unexpected went wrong
                    Dim pbCancel As Boolean
                    Me.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "MarkDuplicates", p.Name + ": " + ex.Message, String.Empty, 0, pbCancel)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
 
        ' Check if the current row and previous row are the same
        If (currentRow.ToString().Equals(previousRow)) Then
            ' Redirect to duplicate output
            Row.DirectRowToDuplicate()
        Else
            ' Redirect to unique output
            Row.DirectRowToUnique()
        End If
 
        ' Fill previous row with current value for next check
        previousRow = currentRow.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Add two destinations and connect the `Data Flow Paths` to the destinations. When connecting you will have to select the output port.

Don't forget to add some dataviewers for testing purposes.